# Auto delete empty posts

Tags: plugins, php

I'm using IFTTT to post images from a subreddit to my WordPress site, and then WordPress shares those images with their post titles on multiple social sites.

The problem is, IFTTT publishes blank posts on WordPress sometimes. They only have a title but no images. Now the plugin I use for sharing the posts published by IFTTT can't recognize empty posts, and it shares only their title on other social media sites since there is no image.

So my only solution is to auto delete empty WordPress posts. Is there any script or plugin to do it?

Please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to write a [wp_insert_post_empty_content](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_insert_post_empty_content/) filter.

WordPress will already [try and reject empty posts](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.7.2/wp-includes/post.php#L3825):

```php
$maybe_empty = 'attachment' !== $post_type
    && ! $post_content && ! $post_title && ! $post_excerpt
    && post_type_supports( $post_type, 'editor' )
    && post_type_supports( $post_type, 'title' )
    && post_type_supports( $post_type, 'excerpt' );
```

but I guess that logic isn't catching your posts here. So you'll need to work out what your empty posts look like specifically and catch them too:

```php
function wpse390344_empty_posts_filter( $empty, $postarr ) {
    if ( ! $empty ) {
        // TODO: look at $postarr - see wp_insert_post() documentation for format
        //       and decide if this is an empty post you want to reject.
        //       If it is, return true.
    }

    return $empty;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_empty_content', 'wpse390344_empty_posts_filter', 10, 2 );
```